# How to do a Text search against tinyint column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with `tinyint` column. I have a transformer in my app level that will show the text representation of the integer, but now I would like to be able to search Text against that column without adding another column to save the text representation of the integer. I tried the `CASE` but it is not allowed in `where` clause.

Is it possible to search `tinyint` as if it is `varchar` with some magic?

Comment: Please provide the SQL you have tried.  Not too many people will be able to help you without having more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `CASE` in the `WHERE` clause, you may construct logical `AND` conditions which match the strings to their `TINYINT` values, using the input text and a string literal. Your application code must supply the value for `<input_text>` in every condition.

```
WHERE
  (<input_text> = 'ZERO' AND column_value = 0)
  OR (<input_text> = 'ONE' AND column_value = 1)
  OR (<input_text> = 'TWO' AND column_value = 2)
```

If the input text matches the string literal, the rest of the condition matching the integer will be evaluated.  Obviously the `<input_text>` can only exactly match zero or one literal text strings.

That can obviously get unwieldy quickly, since `TINYINT` supports a range of 255 values. You might just consider changing the `TINYINT` column to an [`ENUM` type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) instead.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY column_name ENUM('ONE','TWO','THREE',....)
```

Perhaps a better option than either of these (if `ENUM` cannot be used) is to create a data structure mapping strings in your application code, and pass the integer value into the SQL query after performing a lookup of its corresponding string value in application code.

Finally, a similar option entirety in the RDBMS is of course to create another table mapping int values to strings and perform a JOIN against it.

Comment: I am using Doctrine ORM and enum cannot be the choice. Thanks.

Comment: @PMoubed If you cannot use an ENUM, constructing a `WHERE` clause using conditions as above may be your only option, other than storing the map values in your application code..